# what does ”for ever" in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

> Others will understand that defying China **for ever**—whether by trying
> to break away or by repeatedly electing the island’s current ruling
> party, the pro-independence Democratic Progressive Party (DPP)—will
> bring economic disaster and even attack by the People’s Liberation
> Army.

does "for ever" is a pair or they are independent?or is "defy sb for something" a collocation?
I first thought "for ever" is the same as "forever",but if this is true,the whole sentence  will be weird to understand,because "others who defy china forever will be punished" imply "someone who defy China temporarily will not be punished",which make no sense

Comment: It makes sense that someone who defies China temporarily (but later capitulates and does what China wants) will not be punished. It does say "repeatedly", suggesting it is referring to doing something for a long time (if not literally for all eternity). I'm not really seeing what your problem is. (Unless you believe even momentary defiance of China must bring down immediate punishment, in which case Politics SE might be a better place to ask.)

Comment: "Is _for ever_  a pair?" Yes, it is the same as _forever_.

Comment: In American English, 'forever' is usually written as one word. In British English, you may see it written as two words: 'for ever'. Both mean the same thing.

Comment: (for) ever and ever is an emphasized version of forever

Answer (score 0):

> I first thought "for ever" is the same as "forever"

Yes, that is correct. It just means "forever."

> "others who defy china forever will be punished" imply "someone who defy China temporarily will not be punished"

No, it does not have that implication.